# Указание пути к ключу для фильтрации через переменную

Tags: javascript, фильтрация

Допустим, что у меня есть массив объектов вида:

```
[
    {
        "key1": {
            "key2": "test"
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": {
            "key2": "test1"
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": {
            "key2": "test2"
        }
    }
]
```

Я хочу его отфильтровать в js с помощью функции `.filter`.
Вроде бы, все просто `json.filter(e => e.key1.key2 === 'value')`.
Но при этом я хочу, чтобы можно было подать путь `key1.key2` через переменную, так как путь могут прислать снаружи.
Я хочу понять, реально ли это реализовать **без использования `eval()`**. Снаружи этот путь поступает в виде строки. То есть фактически хочу увидеть что-то типа:

```
let variable = "key1.key2"
json.filter(e => e.variable === 'value')
```

Но понятно, что это так не работает. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов (если в названиях ключей может быть точка, вместо строки можно сразу передавать массив подключей):

```js
const data = [
    {
        "key1": {
            "key2": "test"
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": {
            "key2": "test1"
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": {
            "key2": "test2"
        }
    }
];

function filterByKeys(array, keys, value) {
  return array.filter(
    (object) => {
      let currentObjectOrValue = object;
      for (const key of keys.split('.')) {
        currentObjectOrValue = currentObjectOrValue[key];
      }
      return currentObjectOrValue === value;
    }
  );
}

console.log(filterByKeys(data, "key1.key2", "test"));
console.log(filterByKeys(data, "key1.key2", "test1"));
console.log(filterByKeys(data, "key1.key2", "test2"));
```

Comment: _«если в названиях ключей может быть точка, вместо строки можно сразу передавать массив подключей»_ == `▲`

Comment: Если добавить перед return'ом выражение `keys = Array.isArray(keys) ? keys : keys.split('.');` (и далее в цикле просто `of keys`) - такая возможность передачи ключей массивом будет прям "искаропки", не заменяя собой возможность указания в строке через точку.

Answer (score 2):

```js
Array.prototype.filterByNestedProp = function (path, cb) {
  path = path.split('.'); 
  const getNestedObjPropValue = obj => path.reduce(
    (rslt, prop) => rslt && rslt[prop]
  , obj); 
  return this.filter(obj => cb.call(obj, getNestedObjPropValue(obj))); 
}; 


const arr = [
  { "key1": { "key2": "test" }}, 
  { "key1": { "key2": "test1" }},
  { "key1": { "key2": "test2" }},
  { "key1": { "key2": "test3" }},
]; 
// `v => v === значение` как-то скучно, поэтому с регуляркой (найдет 2 объекта)
const testRslt = arr.filterByNestedProp('key1.key2', v => /[12]$/.test(v)); 
console.log(testRslt);
```